# Firefox with opened firebug console throws too much recursion using sammy.js and knockout.js

Tags: javascript, firefox, knockout.js, firebug, sammy.js

After last update of firefox (I asssume) I have problem with firebug console. In my app when I  combine `app.refresh()` with setting observable on get "too much recursion" is thrown and firefox is not responding. When I close firebug console everything works well.

In my viewmodel I have:

```
self.firstStep = ko.observable();

var app = Sammy(function () {
    this.before({ only: { verb: 'get', path: URL.FirstStep } }, function (context) {
        console.log("before");
    });

    this.get(URL.FirstStep, function () {
        self.firstStep(new firstWindow());
        console.log("get");
    });
});

self.LoadData = function () {
    $.ajax({
        //...
        success: function (data) {
            //here is commented out because of debuging the problem
        },
        complete: function () {
            app.refresh();
        }
    });
};

app.run();
self.LoadData();
```

Get in console is logged once, before is logged twice. When I comment out `self.firstStep(new firstWindow())` get is fired twice too.
In chrome everything works fine. Help really appreciated. 
**EDIT: @Mörre** 
When I modify code like:

```
this.get(URL.FirstStep, function() {
  self.firstStep = ko.observable();
  self.firtStep(new firstWindow());
  console.log("get");
});
```

it is working.

Comment: You very likely still have the issue when you close Firebug, but you don't notice it. I had some of those myself, they are always errors in your code. I, for example, called a destroy function from another destroy function that called that first destroy function - endless loop.

Comment: Maybe you are ritght but whole page is loading and functionality works well. When I turn on console page crashes. Chrome works with console open and can't see any error.

Comment: So what - my page worked too when I ignored the error (learned about that error only after months during debugging, like you now, I guess), I still bet it's an error in your code. Fix it and you'll benefit, unless you only care about "just want it to work don't care about errors". Sorry, I won't help with the actual issue - have to debug my own code right now, just wanted to say what I said :)

Comment: I don't say I won't fix it. I am still trying to do this. Thanks anyway ;]

Comment: I had to restart my PC, still don't know what caused issue. Thx

Comment: One last piece of advice. Debugging this may not be easy, I did it by disabling a lot of code until the error was no longer present, and then re-enabling the code piece by piece. Don't try this as an intellectual exercise (unless you find the cause quickly) - this is more brawn over brain. In cases such as this it may be (much!) faster than the brain-approach.

Comment: a bit late, but I encounter this issue too in my app. Seems like a firebug issue, fixed in Firebug 2.0 See https://code.google.com/p/fbug/issues/detail?id=4938

Comment: @sly7_7 thanks for info, I have never encountered this issue againg sadly, but great if they fixed it. Thx for info.

Answer (score 0):

Disable the "Script" panel fix the issue for me, if you don't need to debug JavaScript using the "Script" panel.